# Add new fields inside modal window on change at select (rails_admin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I have:
When I click button "Add new" - I have modal window made by rails_admin with select and options there. Select element have id "#select_from_modal"

I want:
when user changing option in *#select_from_modal* - to add new fields in this modal window and save form.

I know, that I can add custom js by adding file to assets/javascripts/rails_admin/custom/file.js and I did it.

My code is:

```
$(document).on("change", "#modal", function() {
  $('#select_from_modal').change(function() {
    alert('hello!')
  });
});
```

But it have strange behaviour. When I changing select option for the first time - nothing happens. For second time - I have alert 'hello'. For third time - I have this alert twice. Then 3 times, 4, and so on.

Please, help me to understand what am I doing wrong and how to make it in right way?

Comment: Not enough context to give you any better code but you are binding the event with the alert over and over again, it not saying hello! on the first change makes total sense too. To fix this you need a fresh approach

Comment: But I can't go on from this point.
If I will add code with adding some new elements in modal window - it would cause the same behaviour.
For example: http://pastie.org/private/zqdhmblgwkaggknwlpst6q

So, I will have no "legend" for the first time, then +1, +2 and so on.

Comment: @ThomasR.Koll R. Koll In this example, I binded event on click for create button, but have the same result.

Comment: Of course you have the same result as your whole approach is flawed. Scratch it and start with a new approach where you don't create event bindings from inside event bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use event delegation, e.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document.body).on('change', '#select_from_modal', function() {
        alert('hi');
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, this is helpful. Thanks.